# RE : Installing Ubuntu on a NTFS Flash Drive

Tags: boot, windows, ntfs, yumi

I wanted to create a bootable Windows and Ubuntu on my flash drive. Due to FAT32 constraint on Windows, I formatted my flash drive to NTFS. But after i installed Ubuntu into the flash drive and boots it, It keeps giving error running it.

Im currently using YUMI to create all these bootable stuffs and had a 32GB USB3.0 to store these inside. Hope i can get a clear and dumb-proof solution. (Sorry if i'm asking too much)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can install Ubuntu to a NTFS flash drive.

Using FAT should allow it to work.

Using `ext4` is recommended as it's linux native. The only downside is you can't access any files from the drive while in Windows.

If you have a big enough flash drive, try creating a small FAT32 partition for storing data and then creating an ext4 partition for storing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an MBR on the drive, and then partition it in two pieces one being Fat32 or NTFS and the other being ext3/ext4. All that being said, YUMI would have to re-write all of the partition tables when it is writing the iso's. I think that this will get you going in the right direction: [link](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/)

When you install Ubuntu, it generally rewrites everything to ext3/ext4. NTFS is a Microsoft file system that Ubuntu would have overwritten. If you have Ubuntu installed, it can write to an NTFS partition if you have the package ntfs-3g installed. [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions)